# Set Default defaultSession.cookie in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, session-cookies, ejs

Basically, I need something that works in express and node.js With the behavior of electron (of the following function)

```
const { session } = require('electron').remote
const cookies = session.defaultSession.cookies;


cookies.set({
  url: url,
  name:'NAME',
  value: cookie,
  domain:'.project.auth.com',
  path:'/',
  httpOnly:true
}, (error, cookie) => {
    // res.end(error);
});
```

This will set a header called Cookie: NAME = Cookie

In all the files that are requested. (From HTML, JS, CSS among others)

I need something similar but using the EJS template system or if it is not possible.

A method that allows doing this only showing the example file the .png